# How to define separate local and remote variables (PHPStorm, Webstorm)

Tags: javascript, php, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is there a way to define a variable inside of a project that I can reference inside of javascript/php that gets autofilled by webstorm before deployment (local or remote)? As an example, I have the variable:

```
var foo = "/hello/world"
```

This variable is used to define a relative path on the remote server (and is handled by the remote webserver). However, when I use the local webstorm server to do some local tests, it cannot map correctly and I would have to manually alter it to point to:

```
var foo = "http://localhost:1234/hello/world"
```

This makes errors more likely during deployment as I would have to double check each such variable in my project before deploying. My question is whether it is possible to replace these types of declaration with a special webstorm variable that can be customized based on each deployment location or if i can set a custom mapping for certain paths for the webstorm local webserver.

Answer (score 1):

Let say if you are having dynamic URL, you can store it to the JavaScript variable like:

```
var base = "< ? php echo $phpstormurl; ? >";

var relative = '/hello/world';
```

After that you can combine both of them to single one like:

```
var absolute = base + relative;
```

If you alert the path it will show you the full path.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not quite going to work in this case as the local resources being targetted by the url are not on the same port as the webpage. Ideally I would be able to forward particular relative paths to fixed absolute paths locally (just like Apache does for the remote server and its' different resource paths). I was just wondering if there is any configuration file available for the webstorm local web server? That might contain what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The most common solution for this is using [environmental variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable).

These are values that you set on your (local) server outside of your code that can be accessed though [`$_ENV`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php).

```
// Reading an env var with defaults
$foo = getenv("FOO") ? getenv("FOO") : 'bar';
```

There are also tools such as [phpdotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) that can be used to setup env vars from a file in your project.